# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar la lectura de datos con código de VB.Net de una tabla SQLServer (explico)?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Tengo 2 tablas relacionadas por el campo IdHistoria.

- La tabla Historia contiene datos del paciente (es única).
- La tabla de Tratamiento contiene los tratamientos para cada paciente.

En cIdHistoria se indica el número de historia de un determinado paciente y sus datos se obtienen de la tabla Historia y los tratamientos realizados de la tabla Tratamiento (o sea están relacionadas manualmente).

Los datos se obtienen según el código siguiente y funciona, pero cuando la conexión se realiza desde otro ordenador de la red se suele producir un retardo de unos 7 segundos en obtener los datos, pero en el equipo local cargan instantáneamente por lo que creo que el retardo se debe a la forma que accedo a las tablas.

La tabla Historia contiene alrededor de 25.000 filas y la tabla de tratamientos alrededor de 125.000 filas. Creo que debería cargarse más rápido.

¿Cómo puedo optimizar el código para que haga lo mismo sin tardar tanto?

Este es el código que devuelve las filas consultadas según cIdHistoria que se indique:

---

```
        'Dim CadenaDeConexion = "Data source = MIPC; initial catalog = 'Historias'; Connection Timeout = '3'; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = USUARIO;"
    
    Friend Sub CargarDatos(cIdHistoria As String)
      Historia = CargarHistoria(cIdHistoria)
      Tratamiento = CargarTratamiento(cIdHistoria)
      Total = CalcularTotal(Tratamiento)
    End Sub
    
    Friend Function CargarHistoria(cIdCliente As String) As Historia
      Dim Tabla As New DataTable, Fila As DataRow, Datos As New Historia
    
    
      With Datos
        Using AdapdadorSQL As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Historia WHERE IdHistoria = '" & cIdHistoria & "'", CadenaDeConexion)
          AdapdadorSQL.Fill(Tabla)
          Fila = Tabla.Rows(0)
    
          'Pasar los datos de la fila a la clase a devolver.
          .Nombre = Fila("Nombre").ToString
          .Domicilio = Fila("Domicilio").ToString
          .Identidad = Fila("Identidad").ToString
        End Using
    
      End With
    
      Return Datos
    End Function

Friend Function CargarTratamiento() As DataTable
    Dim Tabla As New DataTable

  Using AdapdadorSQL As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Tratamiento, Descripcion, Costo1, Costo2, (Costo2 - Costo1) AS Costo3 FROM Tratamiento WHERE IdHistoria = '" & cIdHistoria & "' ORDER BY IdTratamiento", CadenaDeConexion)
    AdapdadorSQL.Fill(Tabla)
  End Using

  Return Tabla
End Function

Friend Function CalcularTotal(Tabla As DataTable) As DataTable
  Dim Total As New DataTable
  Total.Columns.Add(Nothing, GetType(Double))
  Total.Columns.Add(Nothing, GetType(Double))
  Total.Columns.Add(Nothing, GetType(Double))
  Total.Rows.Add(Tabla.Compute("SUM(Costo1)", Nothing), Tabla.Compute("SUM(Costo2)", Nothing), Tabla.Compute("SUM(Costo3)", Nothing))

  Return Total
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

El código que proporcionaste ya utiliza ADO.NET y parece estar bien estructurado para la carga de datos desde la base de datos. Sin embargo, hay algunas sugerencias que podrían ayudarte a optimizar el rendimiento:

1. **Parámetros SQL**: En lugar de concatenar directamente el valor de
   cIdHistoria en tus consultas SQL, considera utilizar parámetros SQL
   para evitar posibles ataques de inyección SQL y mejorar el
   rendimiento.

   Using AdapdadorSQL As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Historia WHERE IdHistoria = @IdHistoria", CadenaDeConexion)
   AdapdadorSQL.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdHistoria", cIdHistoria)
   AdapdadorSQL.Fill(Tabla)
   End Using

Repite este enfoque en la función **CargarTratamiento** también.

2. **Índices de Base de Datos**: Asegúrate de que las columnas utilizadas
   en las cláusulas WHERE y ORDER BY tengan índices en la base de
   datos. Los índices pueden mejorar significativamente el rendimiento
   de las consultas.
3. **Cierre de Conexiones**: Asegúrate de cerrar las conexiones cuando
   hayas terminado con ellas. Puedes hacer esto utilizando la
   instrucción Using o llamando al método Close explícitamente.

   Using connection As New SqlConnection(CadenaDeConexion)
   connection.Open()
   ' Resto del código...
   End Using
4. **Reutilización de Conexiones**: Considera la posibilidad de reutilizar
   la misma conexión en lugar de abrir y cerrar una nueva conexión para
   cada consulta. Abrir y cerrar conexiones puede ser costoso en
   términos de rendimiento.

   Using connection As New SqlConnection(CadenaDeConexion)
   connection.Open()
   ' Utiliza la misma conexión en las consultas...
   End Using
5. **Caché de Datos**: Si los datos no cambian con frecuencia y no es
   crítico obtener la información más actualizada en todo momento,
   puedes considerar implementar algún mecanismo de caché para
   almacenar temporalmente los datos.
6. **Proceso Asíncrono**: Si estás desarrollando una aplicación que debe
   responder rápidamente, puedes considerar la posibilidad de realizar
   la carga de datos en un hilo separado para evitar bloquear la
   interfaz de usuario mientras se realizan las consultas.

Ten en cuenta que estas sugerencias pueden variar en su efectividad dependiendo de la configuración específica de tu base de datos y la red. Realiza pruebas de rendimiento después de aplicar estos cambios para evaluar su impacto.

Comment: Gracias, creo que el principal cuello de botella son las conexiones. Abro y cierro reiteradamente, en lugar de eso voy a probar abriendo una conexión durante toda la vida del programa y cerrándola solo al salir.